# How to stop a java thread of TestNG through a stop button in swt

Tags: java, selenium, swt, testng

I have created a swt application which starts automated testing using TestNG through command line in java. Now I need a stop button to stop its execution in the middle. Is there a way to do it if when running TestNG with the button doesn't open a new cmd window??

Answer (score 1):

TestNG doesn't provide such API and you'll have to find a workaround.

Not simple, but, for example, you can do is the same thing than the eclipse plugin:

1. Running TestNG in its own java process
2. Link the process and the one of your application in order to have test notifications (could be a bit complicated)
3. Kill the process if/when you want

Comment: Hi Can you please explain it in some detail so I could try it in my code.

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html It should help.